# What is the best way to support night mode?

Tags: android

I implemented the night mode (with the help of Chris Banes's post about DayNight https://medium.com/@chrisbanes/appcompat-v23-2-daynight-d10f90c83e94) in the latest app I'm working on but even if it's working, I'm not sure it's the best way to do it.

To summarize, I added a switch button in my settings to enable/disable it just like in the twitter app. But when the user do it, it doesn't directly switch the them from night to day or from day to night.

To force that, when the user switch, I restart the activity this way (because using activity.recreate is displaying a transition :

```
finish();
startActivity({currentActivity});
overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
```

And as it's a second level activity, when I go back to my root activity, I also have to restart it the same way I showed before.

Do you achieve day/night mode more or less the same way I do or do you have a cleaner to do it ?

Comment: Isn't there a DayNight theme in android now?

Comment: Yeah, there is. https://medium.com/@chrisbanes/appcompat-v23-2-daynight-d10f90c83e94

Comment: Yes, there is a DayNight theme and it's what I'm using. I'll edit to mention that.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware this is more or less the standard way since restarting the activity is necessary for theme changes. I did some browsing, and it appears to be standard.